# Anchor the rear hand

Tags: meaning

Hi everyone what does "Anchor the rear hand"?. I just recently started watching the TV series Arrow and on one of the episodes someone said "Anchor the rear hand".

Does it mean to attack the weaker hand?

---

[*Source*](http://foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=172&t=10209#.U6oA6HDbOZE)  (about 30 lines in)

Comment: [I found a transcript for this](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/S52244092a2/Arrow/Legacies/Me+getting+killed+isn%27t+how+we+do+things,+either,+is+it%3F). Unfortunately, it doesn't make any more sense in context. Are you relying on the subtitles for this quote? Sometimes subtitles get transcribed incorrectly.

Comment: The context for this quote is two men are involved in some kind of martial arts training, fighting with a metal bar in each hand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to bother researching the exact context any further than to note that it's in [the full transcript of the show](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=arrow&episode=s01e06), which seems to be about a news team operating in some physically precarious conditions. The speaker says...

> Me getting killed isn't how we do things, either, is it? Is it? Get in the van! Anchor the rear hand, Diggle.

So my guess is he's asking Diggle to [anchor](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anchor) (hold on to, or otherwise secure) *his* (the speaker's) "rear" hand while he leans forward with his "front" hand holding a camera or microphone. He presumably want to be "anchored" so he doesn't fall out of the van and maybe get killed.